# How many functions $f: \{1,...,n_1\} \to \{1,...,n_2\}$ are there such that if $f(k)=f(l)$ for some $k,l \in \{1,...,n_1\}$, then $k=l$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many functions $f: \{1,...,n_1\} \to \{1,...,n_2\}$ are there such that if $f(k)=f(l)$ for some $k,l \in \{1,...,n_1\}$, then $k=l$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Could you please provide some details as to what you have tried, and where exactly you got stuck? This way, it makes it easier for members to help you! For example, what happens when $n_2 < n_1$?

Comment: why measure theory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $n_2\ge n_1$ we have $$n_1!\binom{n_2}{n_1}$$ functions.

Note that $f(1)$ has $n_2$ choices and $f(2)$ has $(n_2-1)$ choices and so forth.

Thus we have $$(n_2)(n_2-1)(n_2-2)...(n_2-n_1+1)=n_1!\binom{n_2}{n_1}$$

functions.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the number of injective functions from $\{1,\ldots,n_1\}$ to $\{1,\ldots,n_2\}$. This is $$n_1!\binom{n_2}{n_1}$$ if $n_1\le n_2$ and $0$ otherwise.